# Vue.js Filter by dropdown if word is found in array (not exact match only)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter

https://jsfiddle.net/75f3c2po/

How can I make the above Vue.js code filter by dropdown match to the entire array even if there's commas separating other words?  Right now it only matches if the `type: BMW` but I'd like it to also show cards that might have something like `type: BMW, Ford`.

Also, I'm super new to Vue, was hoping someone could also show me how I could have it update as soon as a `select` option is selected without having to hit the "search" button?

Thanks so much

Comment: Use the `on-change` option to automatically update your filters. In your case it would look like this `<select v-model="selectedType" @change="search">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to find by type you could split your type string by a comma, and check if the array includes the value:

```
      this.searchResult = this.items.filter(function(item) {
        let filtered = true
        if (filterType) {
          filtered = item.type.split(',').includes(filterType)
        }
        if (filtered) {
          if (filterCountry && filterCountry.length > 0) {
            filtered = item.country == filterCountry
          }
        }
        if (filtered) {
          if (filterYear && filterYear.length > 0) {
            filtered = item.year == filterYear
          }
        }
        return filtered
      })
```

To be able to search immediately you could use `@change` handler on your selects:

```
<select v-model="selectedType" @change="search">
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: it seems to only be filtering if the word it's looking for is first in the array.  Are you able to help me have it so it looks for the word in any order?  See here: https://jsfiddle.net/9vLhkomn - Thanks!

Comment: yeah, the problem that JS is a case sensitive language, and you should have your values in the same case. For example to use `.toLowerCase()` method (`filtered = item.type.split(',').includes(filterType.toLowerCase())`). Also you should remove empty spaces from you data list, or remove unnecessary spaces using `.trim()`, when you split the string by a comma. Check it our https://jsfiddle.net/cqp29d7t/3/

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I've provided a snippet below based on your fiddle.

Changed your `searchResults` property to a computed property, so that it updates automatically when it detects a change in the `selectedType`, `selectedCountry` or `selectedYear`.

To check against the type, I would first split your csv list and then check if the type exists in that array. I've done that using `item.type.split(',').map(x => x.trim()).indexOf(filterType) !== -1;`

Make sure you understand the basics of Vue and read [Computed Properties and Watchers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    selectedType: '',
    selectedCountry: '',
    selectedYear: '',
    items: [{
        name: 'Nolan',
        type: 'mercedes, ford',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england'
      },
      {
        name: 'Edgar',
        type: 'bmw',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'belgium'
      },
      {
        name: 'John',
        type: 'bmw, audi',
        year: '2019',
        country: 'england'
      },
      {
        name: 'Axel',
        type: 'mercedes',
        year: '2020',
        country: 'england'
      }
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    searchResult: function() {
      let filterType = this.selectedType,
        filterCountry = this.selectedCountry,
        filterYear = this.selectedYear

      return this.items.filter(function(item) {
        let filtered = true
        if (filterType && filterType.length > 0) {
          filtered = item.type.split(',').map(x => x.trim()).indexOf(filterType) !== -1;
        }
        if (filtered) {
          if (filterCountry && filterCountry.length > 0) {
            filtered = item.country == filterCountry
          }
        }
        if (filtered) {
          if (filterYear && filterYear.length > 0) {
            filtered = item.year == filterYear
          }
        }
        
        return filtered;
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.list-item {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
  width: 400px;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedType">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Type</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="bmw">BMW</option>
  </select>

  <select v-model="selectedCountry">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Country</option>
    <option value="belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="england">England</option>
  </select>

  <select v-model="selectedYear">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Year</option>
    <option value="2019">2019</option>
    <option value="2020">2020</option>
  </select>

  <div class="list-item" v-for="item in searchResult">
    <div class="card">
      <p>Name: {{ item.name }}</p>
      <p>Car: {{ item.type }}</p>
      <p>Year: {{ item.year }}</p>
      <p>Country: {{ item.country }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  It seems to only be filtering if the word it's looking for is the first word amongst the comma separated list.  Is there a way to have it so it looks for the word in any order? So like `BMW, Ford` and `Ford, BMW`?

Comment: @adamwstl I've added a `.map(x => x.trim())` to remove any spaces that were in the array elements

Comment: Thank you! appreciate the follow up

Comment: @adamwstl Not all of your items have a `specialties` so you need to check it exists as well, i.e. `filtered = item.specialties && item.specialties.split(',').map(x => x.trim()).indexOf(filterSpecialties) !== -1;`